# images won't display after hosting website on a server

Tags: image, server, cyberduck

Help!
I made a website with downloaded images inside the directory, in an img folder. I am certain that the images are pointed right, because when I work locally, it displays just fine. All I did when uploading to the server was copy and paste the entire project folder over, and I know that none of the files got jumbled up, I inspected and checked. Now when I go on the server, many of the images won't display. I am certain they're pointed right! Locally they work fine.
I'm stumped, even other images on other pages of the site work fine, and they use the same method of the src coming from a saved image from a filepath...
I'm using cyberduck if that helps, I don't know what to do and the project is due tomorrow.
Checking the console gives me 404
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://sites.westmec-coding.org/~eciudad/ProjectPortfolio/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio-gh-pages/img/StPatricksDay.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
But I literally see the image folder in there with it on the cyberduck GUI

Comment: This is too vague, and the link doesn't work (responding with a time-out). Please provide some code, how you've linked stuff, a couple of filenames of the files that doesn't work, make sure you have the exact, correct case for each folder and file and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
Somehow, all the .png's became capitalized to PNG when moved to the server.
I went back in and renamed it to lower case png, capitalization can effect things drastically. The console works miracles.